# How do I create a text file with a text-only formating?

Tags: powershell, text, format

I'm prety new to PowerShell (and not very good with english either), and I've just faced my first problem that is big enough to ask it on a forum. But lets make it short.

I have a script that takes a list witch consist in a number followed by a name both separated by a space. And I need it to conserve this structure, but the software crashes when I let it read the file created by the script.

I've been doing some tests and there were something that helped me, and it was to take a file created by the software and manualy paste the text of the file created by PowerShell. When I was going to save the file, wordpad showed me a prompt that sais:

"You are about to save the document in a text-only format, and this is gonna erase all the formating"

I clicked ok, and later in the software, all worked fine.
This is the script I've been using to create the text file:

```
cls
$formats = "legacy", "standard"
$prefixname = "GF META"
$sideboard = "Sideboard"

$i=0
do{
    $url = "https://www.mtggoldfish.com/metagame/$($formats[$i])/full#paper"
    echo $url
    $html = Invoke-WebRequest $url
    $mainDeck = $html.parsedhtml.getElementsByClassName("archetype-tile")
    echo $mainDeck.length
    $e=0
    do{
        $sUrl = "https://www.mtggoldfish.com/archetype/$($mainDeck[$e].id)"
        echo $sUrl
        $shtml = Invoke-WebRequest $sUrl
        $smainDeck = $shtml.parsedhtml.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where{ $_.name -eq "deck_input[deck]" }
        $deck = $smainDeck.value
        $deck = $deck -split '\n'
        $nmainDeck = $shtml.parsedhtml.getElementsByClassName("deck-view-title")
        $nname = $nmainDeck[0].innerText
        $fullname = $nname.Substring(0,$nname.Length-23)
        $tfullname = "$prefixname $($formats[$i]) $fullname"
        $deckFile = "[metadata]`nName=$tfullname`n[Main]"
            $n =0
            do{
            $compare = $deck[$n][0]
            echo $compare
            if ($deck[$n][0] -eq 's'){
                $deckFile = "$deckFile`n[Sideboard]"
            }else{
                $deckFile = "$deckFile`n$($deck[$n])"
            }
            $n +=1
        }while($n -le $deck.Length)
        $deckFile = $deckFile.ToString()
        echo $deckFile
        $deckFile | Out-File "C:\Users\aleja\Desktop\Mazos\$tfullname.dck"
        $e += 1
    }while ($e -le $mainDeck.length)
    $i += 1
}while ($i -le $formats.Length)
```

Thank you very much for you attention.
(btw the software is mtg Forge, and the file is a deck)

Comment: Add `-Encoding Ascii` to `Out-File`. Default encoding is Unicode. Most likely, Forge can't handle Unicode.

Comment: mmm - perhaps scratch that. [Forge needs UTF-8 encoding](https://www.slightlymagic.net/wiki/DotP_2014:_Frequent_Modding_Mistakes). If `Ascii` doesn't work, try `-Encoding UTF8`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Sir you deserve all the good things that happens to you, the problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - Propose this as a formal answer, so that the querent can accept it and show the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default encoding of `Out-File` is Unicode but [Forge expects UTF-8 encoding](https://www.slightlymagic.net/wiki/DotP_2014:_Frequent_Modding_Mistakes).

Change writing the file with default encoding

```
$deckFile | Out-File "C:\Users\aleja\Desktop\Mazos\$tfullname.dck"
```

to explicitly use UTF-8 encoding

```
$deckFile | Out-File "C:\Users\aleja\Desktop\Mazos\$tfullname.dck" -Encoding UTF8
```